# Has amount increased since previous record submission?

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, teradata

I have a table in the below format

```
Name            ID            Amount
Customer 1      1             £100
Customer 1      2             £50
Customer 1      3             £75
Customer 2      1             £0
Customer 2      2             £1000
Customer 3      1             £50
Customer 3      2             £20
Customer 3      3             £10
```

The ID will always indicate the latest field where 1 = most recent, what I need to do if find out what customers saw an increase in value from their previous ID.

For example customer 1 saw 1 increase of £50, customer 2 saw a reduction of £1000 and customer 3 saw 2 increases one of £10 and another at £30.

Help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Is this for SQL Server as the `t-sql` tag implies, or for some version of `ms-access` or even `teradata`? They're quite different products.

Comment: customer1 saw 1 increase of £50 and 1 reduction of £25? what would your end output look like?

Comment: Hi, yes its being run via Teradata which is T-SQL, I added access for further tags unless something was T-SQL specific. Output would simply need to be the Customer Names of those that saw an increase how many increases were seen

Comment: just how many increases or how many and how much? and don't care about reductions?

Comment: T-SQL is *Transact SQL*, Microsoft's SQL dialect. Although you might name Teradata's T-SQL, it's not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c1.*, c2.* 
  from customer c1 
  join customer c2 
    on c2.ID = c1.ID  + 1
   and c2.Name = c1.Name 
   and c2.Amnount < c1.Amnount
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Moving Difference, usually based on LAG/LEAD. This syntax is not supported by Teradata, but can be easily rewritten:

```
Amount -
min(Amount)  -- LEAD(Amount) over partition by Name order by ID)
over (partition by Name
      order by ID
      rows between 1 following and 1 following) as Diff
```

To filter only for increases you can add

```
QUALIFY Diff > 0
```